# Delay on mouse menu out only

Tags: css

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tFva.png)Can anyone help ? I have tried this [CSS Dropdown Menu: Add delay on mouse out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422123/css-dropdown-menu-add-delay-on-mouse-out) but upon leaving the main nav bar option and moving the mouse cursor directly towards the sub menu option the menu disappears? Is there any way to make it to delay so the menu doesn't disappear immediately ?

https://www.waterstreetgallery.co.uk/en/main menu

so far this targets it correctly and transitions the in but not the hover off?

```css
.menu-block_item:hover .menu-block_item-submenu {
    transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a snippet containing the minimal amount of code that reproduces this error? Have a read on creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or look on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: a class menu-items_z is added on hover and remove on cursor's move you can delay remove of this class

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the transition-delay and duration on the non pseudo class as well.

```
.menu-block_item .menu-block_item-submenu {
transition-delay: 1s;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
```

}

If you just have it on the pseudo :hover class then the transition-delay is only applied when the mouse hovers.

The moment the mouse leaves then the transition-delay is no longer applied which is why your menu disappears instantly.

Comment: Thankyou so much ! Any idea how I can locate the non pseudo class?

Comment: assets/style.css has around 200 lines re menu , as far as I can tell this may be it?

Comment: Check out line 99 in that file. It sets transition to 0s. Set it to 0.5s and add below it transition-delay: 1s

Comment: That does it, thank you so much! Any idea what needs to be done to avoid the stutter and change of state outside of menu?  https://vimeopro.com/user5865079/technical                                                                 https://www.waterstreetgallery.co.uk/en/boxing-hares-stoneware-02.html

Comment: I seems like there are additional elements that are hidden/show with the hover event besides just the .menu-block_item-submenu They will also have to have the transition enabled

Comment: // Header desktop menu 
  $(".menu-block_item-submenu").mouseenter(function(){
    var $htmlScrollet = $("html");
    var $fixedTop = $(".header-top");
    $htmlScrollet.addClass("noscroll");
    $htmlScrollet.css('top', 'inherit');
    // $fixedTop.addClass("header-fixedd");
  });
  $(".menu-block_item-submenu").mouseleave(function(){
    var $htmlScrollet = $("html");
    var $fixedTop = $(".header-top");
    $htmlScrollet.removeClass("noscroll");
    // $fixedTop.removeClass("header-fixedd");
  });

Comment: Could it be these events?    -        Found in Global.js

Comment: I think these are the events?

Comment: // Header desktop menu 
  
  $(".menu-block_item-submenu").mouseenter(function(){
    var $htmlScrollet = $("html");
    var $fixedTop = $(".header-top");
    $htmlScrollet.addClass("noscroll");
    $htmlScrollet.css('top', 'inherit');
    // $fixedTop.addClass("header-fixedd");
  });
  $(".menu-block_item-submenu").mouseleave(function(){
    var $htmlScrollet = $("html");
    var $fixedTop = $(".header-top");
    $htmlScrollet.removeClass("noscroll");
    // $fixedTop.removeClass("header-fixedd");
  });